Shower rod adhesive for tile
Need to hang a L shaped shower rod on a tile shower. See photo, red dots indicate the planned hanging area. The shower rod is an adhesive mount. Will this adhesive be strong enough to hold the weight of the rod and curtain? Or do you recommend something else?


You should find an option that is supported with ceiling rods.

Keep in mind that it does not have to hold the curtain. It has to hold up to someone slipping a little bit who yanks on the curtain to catch themselves. Which is a much higher load.

what would keep the tile from peeling off the wall?

@jsotola Nothing. Tile adhesives are not designed for you to stick a load like that on it. If the contact point is small enough, it'll crack and break it off. If it is large enough, it'll rip out the whole tile. It is a matter of time.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if the fasteners could take the weight, any normal shower curtain rail would fail instead, so while the OP does need to fix it properly, it still won't stand up to someone falling

@RohitGupta and locate the rod(s) at a joist(s).

This plan wouldn't outlast a sneeze. If this is your home and not a flipper then you will be nothing short of dissatisfied fairly soon after achieving an adhesive solution.

The only types of adhesives that will carry that massive leveraged load reliably would be epoxy or super glue, which are obviously permanent and staining. Nothing latex or silicone will have nearly the bond to hold long-term.

... there is no need to worry about the base will falling off.

There's your first sign. This product, like millions of others, is made and sold by someone far from you with little regard for your success. They rely on bribery for reviews and weak-sauce remedies when things don't work as claimed.

It does not work. The mounts don’t attach to the wall, the anchors do not work at all (I had to buy replacements) and once it is up, it can not support the weight of the shower curtain or even itself.


I went to Lowes and got some [epoxy] and it has held up super well!


... the rod sagged about 6 inches at the 90 degree bend.

There's your next set of signs. It will disappoint.
Use a bit of critical thinking and ask yourself what else you've ever seen glued to a wall that sticks out that far and carries dynamic weight loads. Then consider alternative products or mounting strategies.

I agree that by itself there is low chance of success for this, even with epoxy glue and proper surface preparation.
If you can screw into the roof, you could install bent pieces of aluminum flat bar against the wall and screwed into the roof. Bolt the mounting brackets to the aluminum strip. This way the leverage will push against the wall. Glue between the aluminum and tile is not strictly necessary but will help.
There will probably still be some amount of sag in the bar, as the geometry is really not very rigid.

(Edited from image on the Amazon sales page)

No need to jerry rig a wall-mounted rod to hang from the ceiling - just get a ceiling-mounted rod to begin with. You'd also be able to add additional supports in the middle of the rod (but would have to consider how the curtains are configured).
